# How to filter Shopify product types which have whitespace in them?

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I have products which "Product type" has white space in them.

[image]

Using given query nothing shows up.

[image: query url]

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong.

Product type is not a tag, so you can't do `/collections/all/TYPE` the types have a separate URL and they are global, a.k.a not tied to a specific collection. So you can't get the types for a specific collection. (the same applies for vendors as well)

The proper URL for type is `/collections/types?q=care%20product`